# Search with line numbers in GNU Ed

Tags: regular-expression, ed

I have recently begun learning `ed`, however I've come to the point where I need to search for text. My first attempt was `ed`'s `/` command, which will show occurrences, but doesn't include line numbers. Is this achievable in vanilla `ed`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `g` + `n` (global + number commands):

```
$ ed -p 'ed> ' file
ed> ,p
tree
apple
lemon
fruit
not
here
pear
apricot
end
ed> g/a/n
2       apple
7       pear
8       apricot
```

Always check the documentation to see all commands available: [POSIX Ed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html) and [GNU Ed](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html).

Answer (score 2):

You may use `=` to output the line number of a line in the editing buffer. To search with some expression `RE` and output the line number of the first hit, use

```
/RE/ =
```

The `n` command outputs the current  line prefixed by its line number.  Applying it to some other line or range of lines is also possible:

```
/RE/ n
```

To get the line numbers of all matching lines, combine `=` or `n` with the `g` command.  Note however that since the default address of the `=` command is the last line of the editing buffer, not the current line, using `=` would output the wrong result with `g` unless we explicitly give it the `.` address. So use

```
g/RE/ .=
```

to get only the line numbers of all lines matching `RE`.

Use

```
g/RE/ n
```

to output all lines matching `RE` together with their line numbers (similar to `grep -n 'RE'` although formatted differently).